# I marinated a skewer with chicken not cooked next to peppers and mushrooms also uncooked and froze them - will i get sick when i cook them?

Tags: food-safety

I marinated a skewer with chicken next to mushrooms and peppers all uncooked then put them in the freezer
will I
 get sick when i cook them?

Comment: What is *next to*, what was the contact between the ingredients? For how long? What was the temperature? How fresh were the ingredients? Please [edit] all this into your question

Answer (score 1):

Restaurants do this sort of thing all the time. The FDA food code would simply require the vegetables, and anything else that touched that chicken, be cooked to an internal temperature of at least 165 for them to be safe. That's pretty conservative, but I tend to agree.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions that must be met for this to be safe:

- Chicken was out of the fridge or freezer for no longer than 30 minutes
- The time from when the chicken first came out of the fridge or freezer to when the chicken-juice-contaminated vegetables went into the freezer was no longer than 30 minutes.
- the time from the chicken coming out of the fridge or freezer to when the chicken-juice-contaminated skewers went into the freezer was no longer than 30 minutes.
- the chicken is not kept in the freezer for more than a few weeks
- the chicken is immediately cooked after exiting the freezer